# Paypal description in order e-mail

Tags: api, paypal

When sending transactions via the NVP API a description of the products is sent using:

L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0

Whilst this shows up on the order confirmation screen it is not displayed on the user e-mail confirmation. This is leading to customers raising disputes as they are not reminded of what they have purchased.

How can I get the description listed under where it says description in the order e-mail?

Comment: You'll need to include itemized cart details in the payment request to PayPal, and then those details will show up in the emails sent to buyers.  You could also use IPN to generate your own custom branded email notifications and include whatever detail you need to.

Comment: @AndrewAngell I thought this code is what provides the itemised details? We do send out our own e-mails but some customers still get confused it appears. Or the e-mails may go to spam folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was looking for is

```
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0
```